# Creating log file for program

Tags: java, log4j

I'm not sure I'm able to ask this question here, if I can't I appologize. 
I'm creating simple class which will connect to database and I want to log the exceptions into file. My question is should I just append the exception into a file or use Apache log4j I mean I can't the idea of log4j. Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't write exceptions to a file - all sorts of things could go wrong (eg, presumably you'd have to open the file first, which could also fail).  No - write using log4j, then re throw the exception (unless you've reason not to).  Don't know what you mean by "I can't the idea of log4j"

Comment: So you're telling me to use log4j because something may go wrong with the file for example, this was what I'm asking, give it as an answer so i can give you "best answer". Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't write exceptions to a file - all sorts of things could go wrong (eg, presumably you'd have to open the file first, which could also fail). No - write using log4j, then re throw the exception (unless you've reason not to).   Thanks :)